# How to define multiple hardware interfaces for ros2 control in the xacro

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure how to define multiple hardware interfaces and assign the right joints.
Does this work?

```
<ros2_control name="RealRobot" type="system">
   <hardware>
       <plugin>steering_hardware/SteeringHardware</plugin>
   </hardware>
   <joint name="steering_joint">
       <command_interface name="position"/>
       <state_interface name="velocity"/>
       <state_interface name="position"/>
   </joint>
   <hardware>
       <plugin>wing_hardware/WingHardware</plugin>
   </hardware>
   <joint name="wing_joint">
       <command_interface name="velocity"/>
       <state_interface name="velocity"/>
       <state_interface name="position"/>
   </joint>
</ros2_control>
```

I'm getting an error when launching the controller manager but I don't know if it's related to this, so I want to make sure this piece is correct at least.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415049/how-to-define-multiple-hardware-interfaces-for-ros2-control-in-the-xacro/) by [guidout](https://answers.ros.org/users/145435/guidout/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2023-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe the way you have multiple hardware interfaces is just to have multiple `ros2_control` tags like so:

```
<ros2_control name="SteeringHarware" type="system">
   <hardware>
       <plugin>steering_hardware/SteeringHardware</plugin>
   </hardware>
   <joint name="steering_joint">
       <command_interface name="position"/>
       <state_interface name="velocity"/>
       <state_interface name="position"/>
   </joint>
</ros2_control>

<ros2_control name="WingHarware" type="system">
   <hardware>
       <plugin>wing_hardware/WingHardware</plugin>
   </hardware>
   <joint name="wing_joint">
       <command_interface name="velocity"/>
       <state_interface name="velocity"/>
       <state_interface name="position"/>
   </joint>
</ros2_control>
```

This works for me, but if anybody sees an issue with this, please comment.

---

Originally posted by [guidout](https://answers.ros.org/users/145435/guidout/) with karma: 25 on 2023-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0